# Stdin problems with structure

Tags: c, struct, scanf

```
struct x_firm
{
    char name[50];
    double lPrice;
    char EIK[14];

    int day;
    int month;
    int year;

};

typedef struct x_firm Firm;
```

I have problem with filling struct data

```
printf("Enter firm name:");
scanf("%50s",&firm->name);
printf("Enter firm EIK:");
scanf("%13s",&firm->EIK);
printf("Enter firm last 5 years price:");
scanf("%f",&firm->lPrice);
printf("%f\n",firm->lPrice);
printf("Enter registration date[dd.mm.yyyy]:");
scanf("%2d.%2d.%4d", &firm->day, &firm->month, &firm->year);
```

The problem is that the lPrice variable isn't initialize and I don't know why!
Please help!

Comment: What's your struct declaration look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`lPrice` is a `double`, not a `float`.  Use the `%lf` formatter.

```
scanf("%lf",&firm->lPrice);
```